# Ошибка: "error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, glut

Пишу код с использованием библиотеки glut на Visual Studio 2019. Работаю на Windows 10 x64.
В коде присутствуют следующие строки:

```
    int main() {

    time_t now = time(0);
    tm* time = localtime(&now);
    srand(time->tm_sec);
    trianguloPascal();
    color1 = (rand() % 100) * 0.01; color2 = (rand() % 100) * 0.01; color3 = (rand() % 100) * 0.01;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) PC[i] = { rand() % 600 + 20, rand() % 440 + 20 };
    puntos();

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Bezier Curves Animation");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMouseFunc(mouseCB);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMotionCB);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Solar, Конфигурация: Release x64 ------
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutBitmapCharacter.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp___glutCreateWindowWithExit.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutMouseFunc.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutPostRedisplay.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutIdleFunc.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutInitDisplayMode.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutDisplayFunc.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutMainLoop.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutInitWindowPosition.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutMotionFunc.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutInitWindowSize.
1>Solar.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glutSwapBuffers.
1>C:\Users\R\source\repos\Solar\x64\Release\Solar.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 12
1>Сборка проекта "Solar.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Переустанавливал glut с разных источников, использовал freeglut, всё равно - результат и ошибки одни и те же.
Что делать?

Comment: а либу в настройках подлинковали?

Comment: @KoVadim да, в свойствах все ссылки на библиотеки указаны

Comment: возможно, там 32/64 битная несовместимость, может библиотеки плохо скачались (всякое бывает)